# Firebase should my user id structure include the words "simplelogin"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, firebase

When I login with simple login and use `authData.uid` I get the return of `simplelogin:1` (with **1** being the id of my user.

My user structure is set up like this:

```
{
    "users":
    {
        "1": { ... },
        "2": { ... }
    }
}
```

And my rules are set up like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $userid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $userid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I am a little confused on how to make it so `/users/1` would work. Does everyone normally make there user structure `"simplelogin:1"` instead of `"1"`?

It's saying I don't have permission to view my user since my `$userid` is `"simplelogin:1"` and not `"1"`

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I normally use `auth.uid` as the node name, so that would translate to `simplelogin:1`. This only matters when you use multiple login methods, which I do. If you know you will only use simple login, using just the id is fine too. What are you looking to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example above, the unique, cross-provider user id is `simplelogin:1`, not just `1`. Using only the integer is problematic, because these user ids are not unique across all providers (Twitter, Facebook, Google, GitHub, etc.) and may have collisions.

It is expected and by-design that the user ids include the prefix for how the user was authenticated. Also note that the format of these user ids may change in the future, so it is not recommended that you attempt to parse them or treat them as human-readable. They are only intended to be unique alphanumeric ids for your Firebase.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This makes a lot of sense.